# Pass data from Modal Viewcontroller to rootController with Swift 3 (don`t Segue)

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a problem.

I need help. I have been looking for a solution for about 5 hours. Unfortunately without success.

My problem is that I have several storyboards and created without Segue.

I would love the selected Tableviewcell title pass to rootViewController.

Here is my code in my ModalViewTable:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let indexNumber = "\(indexPath.row)"

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "addTime", bundle: nil)
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addTimeVC") as! addTimeViewController
    viewController.test = "TESTABCDEF"
    passedValue = ("\(indexNumber)")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have a property `test` in my firstViewController. What is here wrong? 
I've also tried with delegates and closures but without success. Please help me.

Comment: You may need to present the `viewController` you just created. BTW, do you want to go back to your previous VC *or* present a entirety new one?

Comment: If I present it again, then it is nevertheless for the memories not good. I have with
Present (vc, animated: true ...) to the ModalViewController and I want back with dismiss.
With a static var, I can pass the title, but it is not clean or?

Comment: No, using a `static var` will get you into troubles latter on. Please see my answer below for a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
let indexNumber = "\(indexPath.row)"
let indexPath   = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!

let viewController = navigationController!.presentingViewController as! addTimeViewController
viewController.test = "TESTABCDEF"
passedValue = ("\(indexNumber)")
navigationController!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When you present a view controller modally using the `present(_:animated)` method, the view controller that was *presented* has the `presentingViewController` property set to the view controller that *presented* it. In other words, this property contains a reference to the previous view controller.

Comment: I have try this code. The app is crashed. This is the error code: Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1104e8008) to 'timeSheet.addTimeViewController' (0x10e257d68). This is the code for present of the controller:

Comment: @UmitSevim Answer updated! Please try again when you get a chance... :)

Comment: Unfortunately without success. I get the same error again :(.

Comment: @UmitSevim Weird... pls try to copy and paste my code as is. You might have missed something...

Comment: I have also copied your code and inserted without success :). I have no desire to further develop. :D

Comment: I have solved my problem with delegates (protocols). Thanks for your help.